# Shellscript: kill .py after certain time

Tags: python, shell

I have a python programm which I want to 1) start 2) kill after 5 secs ("with the strg+c command") and 3) start again.

I allready tried:

```
timeout 10 sudo python myProg.py
```

But this did not kill myProg.py after 10 sec. It keeps running!
I think my problem here is that myProg.py runs an while(1) loop so if I try something like:

```
sudo python myProg.py
pkill -f myProg.py
```

Which I found in related questions I never get to the pkill line.

It would be really helpful if you can point me in the right direction. (I am on raspbian jessie)

Comment: what is your code doing that you want to restart? You could do all this just using python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This is just for a simple test of my program

Comment: Then timeout will work fine, if you want to background the process and allow yourself to uinput your sudo password use `sudo -b script.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reach the pkill as your script loops infinitely,  you would need to background the process i.e
`sudo python myProg.py &` but if you may want to kill the script after 5 seconds you can use [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) in linux:

```
 timeout 5s python script.py
```

You can specify the signal you want to send with `-s`:

```
 timeout -s SIGINT  5s python script.py
```